# How to add a class to Composer for autoloading?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I have a class called `class.feed.php`, how do I include it to Composer such that when 'vendor/autoload.php' is included or required in my for example `index.php`, the class will also be included?

Note, am still a PHP newbie.

Comment: Well .. you could start by not naming your class files as  `class.foo.php`, because that's extremely shortsighted. Will you also use names `trait.bar.php` and `interface.buz.php`? How will your autoloader know that what you are loading is not a class but an interface?

Comment: Let's ignore the naming convention. assuming the class is called foo.php, how do i include it to composer such that when vendor/autoload.php is called, the class is also called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an example of using composer.

```
{
  "autoload": {
      "psr-0": {"AppName": "src/"}
  }
}
```

Set the structure as follows:

```
 src/
   - AppName/
 vendor/
 composer.json
 index.php
```

place any classes inside the AppName folder, use a namespace for the class relative to src folder.

Classes should have the same filename as class name starting with a capital, for example a class called Demo in AppName:

```
<?php namespace AppName;

class Demo {

   public function __construct(){
    echo 'hi';
   }
}
```

Then in the root create index.php include the autoload from the vendor once composer has been installed.

To use any class call its namespace followed by the class name

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$demo = new \AppName\Demo();
```

Comment: Thanks dave for the succint answer.

Comment: For  me I needed to run `php composer.phar update`, then it worked. Thank you.